# iOS Crash, memory management error when using NSObject+Rx and Then?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crash, rx-swift

iOS Crash, I think it is caused by memory management error when using third party library NSObject+Rx and Then?

Firebase crashlytics reports,

> 已崩溃：com.apple.main-thread
>   EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000104a5be14
>
> 0
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 328 行
>   closure #5 in LoginRegisterInputView.initRegisterUI()
>
> 1
>   Then
>   $S4ThenAAPAARlzCrlE4thenyxyxKXEKF + 32
>
> 2
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 314 行
>   LoginRegisterInputView.initRegisterUI()
>
> 3
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 225 行
>   LoginRegisterInputView.initUI(style:)
>
> 4
>   IOS
>   LoginRegisterInputView.swift - 第 42 行
>   specialized LoginRegisterInputView.init(style:rootVC:)

Here is the code:

```
let registerProtocolLabel = UILabel().then {
            let string = "RegisterIterm".localized().replacingOccurrences(of: "<a>", with: "+").replacingOccurrences(of: "</a>", with: "+")
            let array:[String] = string.components(separatedBy: "+")
            $0.font = mThemeMinFont
            if array.count > 0 {
                $0.attributedText = (array[0].color(mRGBA(120, 120, 120, 1)) + array[1].color(mThemePinkColor).underline + array[2].color(mRGBA(120, 120, 120, 1))).attributedText
            }
            $0.textAlignment = .left
            $0.numberOfLines = 0
            $0.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            $0.rx.tapGesture().when(.recognized)
                .subscribe(onNext:{ _ in
                 AppUtils.jumpToWebView(route: AppUtils.getFunctionUrl(.term))
                }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
        }
```

The code is of bugs and nasty. It is not written by me, not by my colleague.

Now I am in charge of the bugs.

Reading from [then](https://github.com/devxoul/Then), it is very easy.

The object just set its properties in the closure. It does not visit other properties. So it is very ARC, it will not interfere other objects' memory management.

While my colleague's code is not of Then, it did two much.

I think the crash is caused by NSObject+Rx.

[NSObject+Rx](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/NSObject-Rx)'s code is easy, just code sugar.

```
/// a unique DisposeBag that is related to the Reactive.Base instance only for Reference type
    public var disposeBag: DisposeBag {
        get {
            return synchronizedBag {
                if let disposeObject = objc_getAssociatedObject(base, &disposeBagContext) as? DisposeBag {
                    return disposeObject
                }
                let disposeObject = DisposeBag()
                objc_setAssociatedObject(base, &disposeBagContext, disposeObject, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
                return disposeObject
            }
        }
```

Reading from the source code of NSObject+Rx, in the scene above ,I think 
 `rx.disposeBag` is equal to `label.rx.disposeBag`.

It may cause bugs.

RxSwift's source code is a little hard to read.

So what is the crash reason?

Comment: `rx.disposeBag` is referring to the container's `disposeBag` not the `UILabel`'s. For example if this code is in a ViewController, then it is the view controller's `rx.disposeBag`.

Comment: In this case, `rx.disposeBag` is called in the label's `then` closure. So I think the container of `rx.disposeBag` is the label in this time

Comment: You are wrong. $0.rx.disposeBag would be the label's. This is rx.disposeBag without the $0 which means it's the disposeBag of the object the label is declared in, probably a view controller.

Comment: How to check it? The break point does not work.

Comment: If you remove the import that brings in the disposeBag, the error will be `Type 'Reactive<Type>' has no member 'disposeBag'`. Note that the typename is not `Reactive<UILabel>`. Type in your case might be `LoginRegisterInputView`.

Comment: In any case, you haven't posted enough code to track down the crash. Maybe if you include the `LoginRegisterInputView.initRegisterUI()` function and point out which line the code crashed on, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

`rx.disposeBag` will never equal `label.rx.disposeBag`. If your code is crashing here and you suspect the use of Then, try removing it. The compiler will give you different diagnostic messages when used outside a closure used by Then.

If I had to guess, I would investigate the tap gesture recognizer firing when you don't expect it. I would try something like this:

`$0.rx.tapGesture().when(.recognized).takeUntil(self.viewWillDisappear)`

[From this library](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/NSObject-Rx/issues/71).